# How long it takes medium size dog's corpse being decomposed?

Tags: dogs, decomposition

I am not a Biology student or expert. Moved the post from Pets SE.

Around a month ago, my 12 years old dog passed away. And I buried her in our front yard (mostly soil, 1 meter depth, wrapped in some cloth fabric material). The thing is I have a plan to sell my house, but don't have nerve to move away if my dog's corpse have not completely decomposed. There is a hard feeling to leave her like that, you know, the family bond stuff. So it will be relieving if her body are completely decomposed when that happen.

Background I live in Yogyakarta, Indonesia, which has tropical climate. But from the past few month, we have pretty unusual cold temperature during night until around 9 am, because of Australian Cold Monsoon. I mention this in case it has logical factor of how decomposition works.

Comment: Maybe Medical Sciences Stack Exchange is more suitable. Vets can answer this question there.

Comment: That's a very warm climate, about 25'C year average, which causes very rapid decompostion. 1m deep is about the same temperature, according to graphs. The limiting factor for you will be the air in the soil. wet compact clay can be very low on oxygen, and sand has the highest oxygen. to be on the safe side, you can also ask the new owner if you can come back in 2 years to collect the bones and cover the garden, and give him some extra flowers. My guess is that there can still be some non-bone material there for 2-3 years, hairs for 3-4 years. recall your dog, he is in the sky, dont be guilty.

Comment: @com.prehensible “He is in the sky”? Read the question. The poster said the animal is rotting in the ground.